# How to use one ViewModelFactory to provide for all ViewModels with Dagger

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, dagger

How can I implement a generic ViewModel Factory to provide for all of  my project ViewModels?
To be clear, my ViewModels have dependencies (as constructor parameters)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, there is one called [GithubBrowser](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) and but it is not a tutorial, it is a project. You should know dagger for android to do that. Or, you may check the code below:

```
@Singleton
class DaggerViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

This part will create a "generic" viewmodel for your entire app. In that way, the `ViewModel` is created with arguments asigned. After that you need to implement the factory module in your Singleton modules, and including it on the component.

```
@Component(
    modules = [... ViewModelModule::class]
)
interface AppCompoenent{}
```

Now the fun part:

```
    @Suppress("unused")
    @Module
    abstract class ViewModelModule {
        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @ViewModelKey(MyViewModel::class)
        abstract fun bindsMyViewModel(viewModel: MyViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindsViewModelFactory(factory: DaggerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

Since dagger support multibinding you are free to bind as may `ViewModels` as you want.

The ViewModelKey:

```
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

You are basically puting values in a hashmap. These values are your `ViewModel`.

Hit build! Done.After that you just inject a `ViewModelProvider.Facory` in your fragment. Than in your `ViewModel` you can do:

```
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dependency: YourDependency
) : ViewModel() {}
```

To make clear what you requested on the comments. First of all, there is no specific need to know what is happening inside the `DaggerViewModelFactory`, although I don't recommend learning this way because I am a strong fan of "Always knowing what's happening". FYI the `DaggerViewModelFactory` is just a class that accepts a `Map` with every class that extends `ViewModel` as a key, and that class dependencies as a value. When using `Provider<T>` Dagger knows how to find those dependencies but doesn't yet bring them to you, until you have called the `provider.get()`. Think of it as just a lazy initialization.

Now check the `modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)`. It just checks if that class really extends `ViewModel`.

As for your second question, is important to understand the first part. Since `Dagger` supports multibinding, that means that you can provide dependencies using a `Map<Key, Value>`. For example, a `Map<HomeViewModel, Provider<ViewModel>>` will basically tell dagger that give me `HomeViewModel`'s dependencies. Dagger is going to say: How to know which are `HomeViewModel` dependencies? And you respond: I already have defined a Key for that and it's the `HomeViewModel` class itself. So you just create an annotation, combine it with `@Binds` and `@IntoMap`, and on the background Dagger will just perform a `map.put(HomeViewModel::class, AndDependencies)`.

Comment: Should i know how to made the ModelViewFactory or with copy-paste is enought?

Comment: And the VIewModelKey is necessary? I don't know what are for the Target and Retention scopes. Maybe is like a Module for mapping the ViewModels?

Comment: Don't worry, I will add some explorations extra on the post.

Comment: done, please check again

Comment: Thank you so much! Clear and easy to understand!

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Comment: I'm just starting with Dagger in a project and is hard to understand, a lot of things i just made copy-paste without know what they does, you recommend me any way to learn it?

Comment: Well this is kind of advanced when you are a beginner. I have an article on my own on dagger, if you want to learn the basics : https://medium.com/@stavro96/keep-it-simple-with-dagger-2-241d32e14de

Comment: Perfect i go to check it!

Comment: I was seeing your example in Medium but i don't understand the uses of the Scopes, the scope with Retention Annotation is only saying to run the dependency when the app is running, so have no sense made it or at least i don't see it.

Comment: The scope is just a mark, nothing else. Just like override. it doesn't do anything. The only thing it does, is for dagger to know the level of the dependency. If you check the `@Singleton` annotation you will find the same. So scopes define hirearchy. Please check the video of twisted equation on scopes for better understanding.

Comment: Where I can find this video?

Comment: At the end of my article, you have 3 resources to learn dagger. Open the twisted equations, and go to scopes serie

Comment: sorry the name is Dagger 2 Android Tutorial

Comment: I see it and now I understand it, thanks again!

Comment: But there is one think I don't see clear. I know what scopes are for but for example the scope MapKey is mapping my activity so isn't just a mark for know the dependency level no?

Comment: The `@MapKey` by its name doesn't look a scope

Comment: Last question please, to finish understand all: What's the ViewModelProvider.Factory for?

Comment: Since a `ViewModel` has a lifecycle on it's own, you cannot init `ViewModel` with a normal constructor, so you need a factory for it.

Comment: I post a new question if you can help me to fix the issue @coroutineDispatcher  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206369/no-injector-factory-bound-for-class