# No injector factory bound for Class<>

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2, model-view

I saw the same question in stack but they try to fix the error with the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` but in `Dagger` documentation says use `@ContributesAndroidInjector` is only optional, so here are my classes:

My `MainActivityComponent`:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = [
    MainBuilder::class
])
@ActivityScope
interface MainComponent: AndroidInjector<MainActivity>{

    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory: AndroidInjector.Factory<MainActivity>
}
```

My `AplicationBinder`:

```
@Module(subcomponents = [
    MainComponent::class
])
abstract class AppBuilder {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(MainActivity::class)
    abstract fun mainActivityFactoryBind(factory: MainComponent.Factory): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>

}
```

And my `BaseActivity` who extends my `MainActivity`:

```
abstract class BaseActivity: HasSupportFragmentInjector, AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }
}
```

How i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the dagger documentation says:

> Pro-tip: If your subcomponent and its factory have no other methods or
>   supertypes other than the ones mentioned in step #2, you can use
>   @ContributesAndroidInjector to generate them for you. Instead of steps
>   2 and 3, add an abstract module method that returns your activity,
>   annotate it with @ContributesAndroidInjector, and specify the modules
>   you want to install into the subcomponent. If the subcomponent needs
>   scopes, apply the scope annotations to the method as well.

So basically the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` will generate that subcomponent thing you are doing manually. Since your case matches the `Daggers` documentation on this step, you can freely use `@ContributesAndroidInjector`.

Example:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, ActivityModule::class, BroadCastReceiversModule::class,...]
)
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(pocketTreasureApplication: MyApplication)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: Application): AppComponent
    }
}
```

The `AndroidInjectionModule` is free from Dagger. In that case it tells `Dagger`: Hey we have Android components to deal with and than `Dagger` knows how to generate them.

Than, you should use your modules, like`ActivityModule` to generate your classes that extend `Activities`, `Fragments`, `Services`, `BroadCastReceivers` etc.

So the `ActivityModule hold the`@ContributesAndroidInjector`:

```
    @Singleton
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeMainactivity(): MainActivity
```

And the now `Dagger` knows that you may magically inject dependencies on `MainActivity`.
Same works for the `FragmentModule` inside it.

And than in your `MainActivity` you can do:

`AndroidInjection.inject(this)` and inject your dependencies.

That's all. You may check more into my personal article for Dagger-Android [here](https://coroutinedispatcher.blogspot.com/2019/07/pack-your-bags-were-migrating-to-dagger.html).

Comment: If i want to inject my `ViewModels` should be a module from the Fragment?

Comment: No, Modules don't have a thing to do with Fragments